# How to connect my email attactment form to php. direct my email

Tags: php, html

How to connect my email attachtment form to php. direct my email.

Html :-

```
  <form id="form" class="blocks" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="js/upload_file.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" name="address" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" name="phone" />
    </p>
    <p class="area">
        <label>
            Year Exp:</label>
        <input type="text" class="text" name="exp" />
    </p>

                      <p class="area">
        <label for="file">
            Upload ur CV:</label>
        <input type="file" name="attachment">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
    </p>
 </form>

    <div class="right">
        <img src="images/Careers.png" width="350" height="334">
    </div>

    </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

How to connect my email attachtment form to php. direct my email.
How to connect my email attachtment form to php. direct my email.
How to connect my email attachtment form to php. direct my email.

PHP :-

```
 <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
{
  $domain='www.example.com';
  $from='www.example.com';
  $name = $_REQUEST['name1'] ;
  $add = $_REQUEST['add'] ;
  $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
  $exp = $_REQUEST['exp'] ;
  $attachment = $_REQUEST['attachment'] ;
    $subject = 'Massage recieved from Pearl : '.$domain.'';
    $body = $email.'

    The person that contacted you is : '.$name.'

    |------------------Full Details--------------------|

   Name:            '.$name.'
     Address:          '.$add.'
     Phone:          '.$phone.'
     Experience:         '.$exp.'
     Attachment:         '.$attachment.'

    |--------------------End---------------------------|'; 
  echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Thank you for your feedback. We will contact you shortly')
    window.location.href='http://www.pearlgroup.asia';
    </SCRIPT>");  

mail("info@example.com",$from, $subject, $body);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"

}
else
{
echo "Try again";
}
?>`
```

Comment: can you post your php code?

Comment: please put your php code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question: http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this articles (http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html) that use pear library, after you get the attachment and processing it, then then you can send the email use Mail library ...

```
$message = new Mail_mime(); 
$message->setTXTBody($text); 
$message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file); 
$body = $message->get(); 
$extraheaders = array("From"=>$from, "Subject"=>$subject,"Reply-To"=>$visitor_email); 
$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders); 
$mail = Mail::factory("mail"); 
$mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

If you want to use swift (http://swiftmailer.org/), the logic still the same ...

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subjct', 'Body message');
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/file'));
```